# Rewrite internally from one URL (some path) to another URL (another path)

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite, mod-proxy

Is it possible to rewrite/proxy a URL to another URL having different paths ?
It should not be just a redirect, and should be a internal proxying to the other URL, so that the browser address bar shows the original URL only.
Note, the domain/hostnames will be different for both the URLs.
Please suggest.

```
e.g.
Rewrite or Proxy from, 
https://www.example1.com/a/b 
to
https://www.example2.com/p/q/r
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, it's just a basic proxy. Apache doesn't care if the target is another server or itself (as long as you don't create a loop). It however also allows the same content to be viewed over different URLs, which is a behavior that is punished by search engines. I'd advise against it.

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is a simple proxy that can be done with mod_proxy of apache.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_proxy.html

e.g. in your virtualhost vonf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName streaming.domaine.tld
    ProxyPass /a/b/ https://www.example2.com/p/q/r/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it gives 404 error on accessing https://www.example1.com/a/b/ rather than proxying and returning the page from https://www.example2.com/p/q/r/. Please note that /a/b/ is intended to be not present on example1.com and some rewrite along with proxying should happen to reach to example2.com/p/q/r. Please suggest.